# Media Query Browser Smart TV

Tags: browser, media-queries, smart-tv

Is there a css media query for Smart TVs?

I tried this way but it did not work:

```
@media tv and (min-width: 700px)  {
   body { border: 1px solid red;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got here by testing a Samsung TV 40' she receives a media query with resolution of 1240px

Worked here:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1240px) {...}
```